# Combinatorially check relationship for all entities in a sentence

Tags: java, combinatorics

I have a sentence of the following form:

```
<sentence> 0
A sports article in some copies on Sunday about <LOCATION>Boston</LOCATION> 's 1-0 victory against <LOCATION>San Francisco</LOCATION> referred incorrectly to the history of the interleague series between the <ORGANIZATION>Red Sox</ORGANIZATION> and the <ORGANIZATION>Giants</ORGANIZATION> .
</sentence>
```

Within the sentence are references to entities, i.e.

```
Boston
San Francisco
Red Sox
Giants
```

I want to "combinatorially" evaluate them to determine if they have some relationship.

So I have some function that will tell me if they are related, and I want to write a function that will check, for instance:

```
Boston        X San Francisco
Boston        X Red Sox
Boston        X Giants
San Francisco X Boston
San Francisco X Red Sox
San Francisco X Giants
Red Sox       X Boston 
Red Sox       X San Francisco
Red Sox       X Giants
Giants        X Boston
Giants        X San Francisco
Giants        X Red Sox
```

How to write such a function?

Comment: so assuming you already have the function (Are related) and stringArray then its just two nested for loops (say on i and j) with an additional i != j to exclude the diaganol.  You explicitly said you want to check A X B AND B X A but should the relationship be symetirc you can skip the transpositions with j <  i instead.

Comment: that sounds good, but could you show me what that would look like in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 'full square, excluded diagonal' as you've asked for its

```
string[] teams = {"Boston","San Francisco","Red Sox","Giants"};
for (string home:teams) 
{
  for (string away:teams) 
  {
     if (home==away) continue;
     System.out.println(home + " x " + away);
  }
}
```

You can alternatively use a for loop with i, j etc.  You would need to use that case in general if you want to de-duplicate A X B and B X A